# Picking k numbers from 1 - 100

Tags: game-theory

Assume A and B play a game with C.

C will pick a random number from $1$ to $100$, and A and B both pick $k$ different integers between $1$ and $100$ inclusive.

Say A picks $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$, B picks $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_k$, and C picks $c$.

Player A is said to win the game if $$\min(|c-a_1|, |c-a_2|, |c-a_3|) > \min(|c-b_1|, |c-b_2|, |c-b_3|)$$ (the example shown above is when $k=3$)

What's A best picks such that the winning chances for them are higher?

For $k = 1$ and $k = 2$, the answers are trivial, being $50$ or $51$, and $33/34$ and $66/67$ each.

For $k = 3$, are the answers $25, 50$, and $75$? And for $k = n$, are the answers between intervals of $\frac{100}{n+1}$?

If A and B both pick the same list of numbers, it's a tie.

Comment: The way you wrote the rules, the choices for A and B are *ordered lists* of numbers, since whether A wins depends only on the first three choices by A and B. [Did you mean that to be?] Also not clear is whether, once A and B have their *sets* of distinct numbers, each may put them in the order they prefer, or whether on the other hand each must use the order in which their numbers happen to have been randomly selected.

Comment: 1. No, I meant until k = n. That was if k = 3.
2. That does not matter, does it?

Comment: Oh then you shoud re-write the paragraph after "Player A is said to win the game if" to reflect that. Another thing: What happens if A and B both pick the same list of numbers? Is it a tie?

Comment: Yes, it's a tie.

Comment: Are you sure your inequality is right? Because here A would win if it has the larger minimum error, i.e. makes a worse "best guess".

Comment: Not sure about the k=2 case. If B knew about A's choices, he would choose 32 and 68, and win 65% of the time. Would the best strategy not be splitting 1-100 into n intervals, and choosing the centre of each interval? So 25/26 and 75/76 for k=2.

Comment: @haavbj, yes your interpretation is correct. Jaap, how about assuming that A and B does not know any of the other's choices?

Comment: If B chooses the same strategy and therefore the same  numbers as A then A will not win..

Comment: Even if A's strategy is impacted by some random elements, then again B can use the same strategy and has the same chances as A to win or loose. There is no difference between A and B, so there is no strategy that gives A an advantage.

Comment: @miracle173, true but definitely picking {1, 2, 3} is definitely worse than picking {25, 50, 75}. Also, I think the goal here is to not lose, and survive as many rounds as A can.

Answer (score 1):

Lets choose from the interval $[0,1]$ instead from the numbers $1,\ldots,n$.
You claim that choosing $\frac 1 3, \frac 2 3$ is optimal for $k=2$. But that is  not true. Bob chooses $\frac 1 3-\varepsilon, \frac 2 3+\varepsilon$ and its chances to win are $\frac 2 3-2\varepsilon$.

For Alice it is better to choose $\frac 1 4, \frac 3 4$. If Bob chooses both numbers from $(\frac 1 4, \frac 3 4)$ he will win with probability of smaller  than $\frac 1 2$, e.g with probability $\frac 1 2-2\varepsilon$ for choosing $\frac 1 4+\varepsilon, \frac 3 4 -\varepsilon$. If Bob chooses $\frac 1 4-\varepsilon, \frac 3 4 +\varepsilon$ the probability is $\frac 1 2-2\varepsilon$ , too. If one number is from $(\frac 1 4, \frac 3 4)$ and the other either $\frac 1 4-\varepsilon$ or $\frac 3 4 +\varepsilon$ then the probability  is $\frac 1 2-\varepsilon$, too.
All in all, the best  numbers for  Bob are $\frac 1 4$ and $\frac 3 4$, too.

These  arguments can be extended  to $k>2$
Alice should divide $[0,1]$ into $k$ subintervals of equal length and then choose the center of each subinterval. This means Alice should choose
$$\begin{eqnarray}a_1&=&\frac 1 {2k}\\
a_2&=&\frac 3 {2k}\\
&\vdots&\\
a_k&=&\frac {2k-1} {2k}
\end{eqnarray}$$